# add div tag in invoice configuration in odoo 12

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

can anyone please help me regarding invoice configuration in odoo 12.
i am trying to add div tag inside invoice configuration page but got no success.

```
<record id="res_config_inherit_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.config.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.res_config_settings_view_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('app_settings_block')]" position="inside">
            <h2>Notification</h2>
            <div></div>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

i have inherited transient model of res.config.settings in my py file.

Comment: Have you tried using <p>test</p> instead of an empty div? Maybe it didn't show because it was empty?

Comment: hey, thanks for your suggestion, i have solved it today early in the morning. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just changed reference from **base.res_config_settings_view_form** to **account.res_config_settings_view_form** and
in xpath i added **data-key** which is sat in the div tag of class named **app_settings_block** in account.res_config_settings_view_form xml,
in account.invoice it adds all the divs of invoice configuration.

```
<record id="res_config_inherit_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.config.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.res_config_settings_view_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="//div[@data-key='account']" position="inside">
                <h2>Notification</h2>
                <div class="row mt16 o_settings_container" id="notification">
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 o_setting_box">
                        <div class="o_setting_left_pane">
                            <field name="unpaid_notification"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                            <label for="unpaid_notification" string="Unpaid invoice reminder"/>
                            <div class="text-muted">
                                Auto send unpaid invoice emails to the partners
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xpath>

        </field>
    </record>
```